# btrfs cannot mount because device replace operation is ongoing

Tags: linux, mount, btrfs

I was transfering data from and disk to a new one. However the new one an seagate IronWolf 12Tb has trouble (may be too sensible to output voltage). Never the less then replace operation stops on with a message I did not take time to note.

So I had to reboot to remove Seagate disk. I perform a btrfs check on the original disk that ends with no errors, stop the server, remove de 12Tb disk and reboot...

With a boot failure as my btrfs device won't mount with :

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdd1,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error

   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail or so.
```

So I perform (as you should did) the : dmesg | tail and get :

```
[ 2833.182505] BTRFS info (device sdd1): disk space caching is enabled
[ 2833.182515] BTRFS info (device sdd1): has skinny extents
[ 2833.321953] BTRFS warning (device sdd1): cannot mount because device replace operation is ongoing and
[ 2833.321962] BTRFS warning (device sdd1): tgtdev (devid 0) is missing, need to run 'btrfs dev scan'?
[ 2833.321969] BTRFS error (device sdd1): failed to init dev_replace: -5
[ 2833.339466] BTRFS: open_ctree failed
```

Well I agree with the situation however the "btrfs replace cancel" require a mount point. And the system refuse to mount... the dog looking ofr his tail.

```
usage: btrfs replace cancel <mount_point>
```

I've made many search and did not find any viable solution. I've search for "replace operation is ongoing" and I hopefully found page with source code of : [dev-replace.c](https://github.com/yandex/smart/blob/master/fs/btrfs/dev-replace.c) where if found this block of code :

```
    /*
     * allow 'btrfs dev replace_cancel' if src/tgt device is
     * missing
     */
    if (!dev_replace->srcdev &&
        !btrfs_test_opt(dev_root, DEGRADED)) {
        ret = -EIO;
        pr_warn("btrfs: cannot mount because device replace operation is ongoing and\n" "srcdev (devid %llu) is missing, need to run 'btrfs dev scan'?\n",
            (unsigned long long)src_devid);
    }
    if (!dev_replace->tgtdev &&
        !btrfs_test_opt(dev_root, DEGRADED)) {
        ret = -EIO;
        pr_warn("btrfs: cannot mount because device replace operation is ongoing and\n" "tgtdev (devid %llu) is missing, need to run btrfs dev scan?\n",
            (unsigned long long)BTRFS_DEV_REPLACE_DEVID);
```

}

Not it's a small advise that the "official" reason of the error is that the btrfs volume is **degraded**.
Hopefully i was reading this page as the same time : [Using Btrfs with Multiple Devices](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Using_Btrfs_with_Multiple_Devices) where I was reading :

> Replacing failed devices
>
> Using btrfs replace
>
> When you have a device that's in the process of failing or has failed in a RAID array you should use the btrfs replace command rather than adding a new device and removing the failed one. This is a newer technique that worked for me when adding and deleting devices didn't however it may be helpful to consult the mailing list of irc channel before attempting recovery.
>
> First list the devices in the filesystem, in this example we have one missing device that we will replace with a new drive of the same size. In the following output we see that the final device number (which is missing) is device 6:

```
enter code here

user@host:~$ sudo btrfs filesystem show
Label: none  uuid: 67b4821f-16e0-436d-b521-e4ab2c7d3ab7
     Total devices 6 FS bytes used 5.47TiB
     devid    1 size 1.81TiB used 1.71TiB path /dev/sda3
     devid    2 size 1.81TiB used 1.71TiB path /dev/sdb3
     devid    3 size 1.82TiB used 1.72TiB path /dev/sdc1
     devid    4 size 1.82TiB used 1.72TiB path /dev/sdd1
     devid    5 size 2.73TiB used 2.62TiB path /dev/sde1
     *** Some devices missing
```

This is not my exact situation as I do not have "*** Some devices missing", however it's quite close. I read the following :

> If the device is present then it's easier to determine the numeric device ID required.
>
> Before replacing the device you will need to mount the array, if you
>   have a missing device then you will need to use the following command:

```
sudo mount -o degraded /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

Here it was the way to mount a degraded btrfs in order to cancel an interupted replace operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here his the full solution :

```
[root@home disk]# mount /dev/sdd1 /store/backup_big_btrfs/
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdd1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
[root@home disk]# dmesg | tail
[ 2833.182505] BTRFS info (device sdd1): disk space caching is enabled
[ 2833.182515] BTRFS info (device sdd1): has skinny extents
[ 2833.321953] BTRFS warning (device sdd1): cannot mount because device replace operation is ongoing and
[ 2833.321962] BTRFS warning (device sdd1): tgtdev (devid 0) is missing, need to run 'btrfs dev scan'?
[ 2833.321969] BTRFS error (device sdd1): failed to init dev_replace: -5
[ 2833.339466] BTRFS: open_ctree failed
[root@home disk]# btrfs replace cancel
btrfs replace cancel: too few arguments
usage: btrfs replace cancel <mount_point>

    Cancel a running device replace operation.

[root@home disk]# btrfs replace cancel /store/backup_big_btrfs
ERROR: not a btrfs filesystem: /store/backup_big_btrfs
[root@home disk]# mount -o degraded /dev/sdd1 /store/backup_big_btrfs/
[root@home disk]# btrfs replace cancel /store/backup_big_btrfs/
[root@home disk]# umount /store/backup_big_btrfs/
[root@home disk]# mount /dev/sdd1 /store/backup_big_btrfs/
```

When you can't mount btrfs due to an failed replace opperation then :

1. Check your btrfs volume
2. mount it with option **-o degraded**
3. cancel the replace opperation
4. unmount the btrfs volume
5. mount it without any option